# Is it possible to get website input from users via a table that can then be sent to a database?

Tags: wordpress, data-entry

I want to set up a website for friends to enter predictions for Saturday football games.
So, I envisage a table with the fixtures with fields to place the predicted scores:

Liverpool----[ ] vs [ ]---Man Utd

Man City-----[ ] vs [ ]---Spurs
etc.
Is it possible to embed an Excel sheet as a means to input the data?
THen on SUBMIT send do an SQL database ?

Answer (score 0):

Can create a form which could be styled as such. It depends on how fancy you want to be and your coding experience.

A simplier solution would be to [use google sheets and create a web input form.](https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-web-input-forms-with-google-sheets--cms-28735)

Comment: Thanks but the link does not show inpout as a table as I requested.